# Bookdown: Using stylesheet removes superscripts from footnotes

Tags: css, r-markdown, epub, bookdown

I have a pesky problem when compiling epub books in bookdown: Including a stylesheet removes the superscript from my footnote numbers. Here's a minimal example:

Define style.css as

```
<style>

h1 { font-size: 26px; color: Black;}

</style>
```

And create an Rmarkdown file with

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::epub_book:
    stylesheet: 'style.css'
---

This is a^[Test]
```

In this case, I get a book with "This is a1" (i.e., with the 1 not superscripted). Removing `stylesheet: 'style.css'` fixes the problem. In that case, I get a book with "This is a<sup>1</sup>" (i.e., with the 1 superscripted).